# Issue writing a generic copy constructor for the base of a CRTP class

Tags: c++, crtp

I've been experimenting with [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) in c++, and I've ran into an issue writing a generic copy constructor for the base class to copy any other derived class. Lets say I have this CRTP base class.

```
template <class Derived>
class Base {
public:
    //Static dispatch function
    void print() const {
        static_cast<Derived *>(this)->print();
    }

protected:
    //Protected so it can only be derived
    Base(int i) : i(i) { }

    //Attempt at a generic copy constructor
    template <class Sibling>
    Base(const Base<Sibling>& rhs) : i(rhs.i) { }

    const int i;
};
```

Now if I write two derived classes: `class Derived1 : public Base<Derived1>` and `class Derived2 : public Base<Derived2>` and I give Derived2 a copy constructor that takes a Derived1 like this:

```
class Derived2 : public Base<Derived2> {
public:
    //Copy constructor
    Derived2(const Derived1& rhs) : Base(rhs) { }
    ...
};
```

I get a compiler error. `error: 'i' is a protected member of 'Base<Derived1>'` This is because Derived1, and Derived2 are two unique types that not inside the same class family so they don't have access to non-public members, correct?

In the Base class If I declare `template <class Sibling>` a class friend of Base it compiles and copies fine, but I only want Base to have access to derived members in the copy constructor. It also works if I change `i` visibility to public, but this ruins any type of encapsulation.

What would be ideal would be to make the copy constructor a friend function of all derived class.

```
template <class Derived>
class Base {
    ...

    //Friend Declaration
    template <class Sibling>
    friend Base::Base(const Base<Sibling>& rhs);

    //Generic copy constructor
    template <class Sibling>
    Base(const Base<Sibling>& rhs) : i(rhs.i) { }

    ...
};
```

But this results in the same compiler error. Have I declared the friend function wrong? Or is this just not possible to do? If so is there any other method to convert from one derived class to another?

Comment: A template constructor is never(!) a copy constructor

Comment: Yes you are correct, huh I did not know that. But the actual copy constructor would only be called when converting Derived classes of the same type while the templated  constructor I defined would still be called when converting Derived of a different type, right?